# Django/Celery - can't see debug logs while running python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, logging, celery

I recently integrated celery==3.1.0 with our companies django project. Please find below the directory structure and few of the code details.

```
website/
    apps/
        app1/
            forms.py
            models.py
            tasks.py
            urls.py
            views.py
        app2/
            forms.py
            models.py
            tasks.py
            urls.py
            views.py
        __init__.py
    settings/
        base.py <- contains base settings
        celery.py
        local.py <- contains dev/prod settings, imports all settings from base.py
__init__.py
urls.py
wsgi.py
```

`website/apps/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.

from website.settings.celery import app as celery_app
```

`website/settings/celery.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings.local')

app = Celery('website.apps')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


# @signals.setup_logging.connect
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

`website/apps/app1/tasks.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

celery settings in `website/settings/base.py`:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
CELERYD_LOG_FILE = None
CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS = False
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL = 0
```

Currently, I have set DEBUG=True on my machine. After running python manage.py runserver, I do not see any debug logs on the console. I just see the requested url and the served static files. Prior to celery setup, I was able to view the debugs logs of the SQL query being executed. I am using django==1.4.12. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do u run celery?

Comment: Yes. I had `celery -A website.apps worker -l info` running on console.

Comment: What is your logging settings?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Currently I have not setup any logging, I am working on local machine.

Comment: May be root cause is from logging settings